# server can't take back control of mouse and keyboard after mstsc

Tags: synergy

I'm using the Synergy v1.8.8-stable on two Windows 7 machines.  The server is 64-bit while the client is 32-bit.  The two computers sit side-by-side with separate monitors.  I use Synergy to share the keyboard and mouse.

Normally things work just fine.  But I often need to mstsc into the server from other desktops at work.  When I come back to my desk, the mouse is visibly stuck on one side of the server's monitor and cannot be moved.  The keyboard is actually controlling the client at this point.

Is there anyway to wrest control of the server's mouse and keyboard using a hotkey or something like that?  The only way I can fix the problem is to mstsc into the server from a remote computer and stop Synergy.  Then I can log back into the server at my desk and restart Synergy.  Everything is fine until I need to mstsc again.

I used to use a program called Share Mouse that allowed a special keystroke to always get back control of the keyboard and mouse on the local machine.  Is there something similar for Synergy?  Or is there something else I can fix in my configuration?

BTW I tried disabling display scaling on the server under synergys.exe since there seemed to be some stuck-mouse issues involving that but it didn't help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple ways to do this.

The method I use is to restart the synergy service (on either the active client or the server). This way I can use various remote access tools that might not have the correct key combinations available to them.

The solution you're looking for is the [switchToScreen() action](https://github.com/symless/synergy/wiki/Text-Config#Actions). You can set (almost) any key combination to switch to any device, or to switch in a specific direction or perform other actions. For example, you could use this in your settings file to set a key combo to switch back to the server:

```
section: options
    keystroke(super+control+shift+home) = switchToScreen(yourServerNameGoesHere)
end
```

This would enable you to press Win+ctrl+shift+home to switch to the device named "yourServerNameGoesHere".